# pass variable on item click from one page to another in ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm working with ionic2 and I have a static list of items (ion-item).

When I click on an item I need to pass a variable (wcyear in this case) to a second page.
The problem is that if I print to console the variable I passed (wcyear) I get undefined.

**Note**: If I replace wcyear with a constant string in `home.ts` (i.e. `year:"helloworld"`) then I see "helloworld" printed in my console.

This makes me think I have an error in my home.html but I can't see it.

**home.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic 2 app
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
<ion-list>
  <ion-item let wcyear="2014" (click)="goToYear(wcyear)">
    <ion-avatar item-left>
      <img src="img/2014.png">
    </ion-avatar>
    <h2>2014</h2>
    <h3>some text</h3>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item let wcyear="2010" (click)="goToYear(wcyear)">
    <ion-avatar item-left>
      <img src="img/2010.png">
    </ion-avatar>
    <h2>2010</h2>
    <h3>some text</h3>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item let wcyear="2006" (click)="goToYear(wcyear)">
    <ion-avatar item-left>
      <img src="img/2006.png">
    </ion-avatar>
    <h2>2006</h2>
    <h3>some text</h3>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item let wcyear="2002" (click)="goToYear(wcyear)">
    <ion-avatar item-left>
      <img src="img/2002.png">
    </ion-avatar>
    <h2>2002</h2>
    <h3>some text</h3>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {YearDashboardPage} from '../year-dashboard/year-dashboard';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})

export class HomePage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.navCtrl = navCtrl;
  }

  goToYear(wcyear){
    this.navCtrl.push(YearDashboardPage, {
      year: wcyear,
    });
  }

}
```

**year-dashboard.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/year-dashboard/year-dashboard.html',
})
export class YearDashboardPage {

  selectedYear
  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private navParams: NavParams) {
     console.log(navParams.get('year'));  // I get undefined
  }

}
```

Comment: what is wcyear `(click)="goToYear(wcyear)"` here ?? from where you get wcyear ? try using `let-wcyear`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
console.log(navParams.get('year'));
```

use

```
console.log(this.navParams.get('year'));..
```